# Pennylane and Qutrit quantum circuit matrix representation bug

Tags: quantum-algorithms, pennylane, quantum-state

I want to find the operator that describes this qutrit quantum circuit. Where a TSub, some TRZ rotations and a TAdd are applied to 2 quitrits. I am using Pennylane 0.34.0. [image: Qutrit circuit]

This is the code:

```
import pennylane as qml

TSub = qml.adjoint(qml.TAdd)

res = qml.TAdd(wires=[0, 1]) @ qml.TRZ(0.5, wires=1, subspace=(0, 1)) @ \
    qml.TRZ(0.5, wires=1, subspace=(0, 2)) @ TSub(wires=[0, 1])

print(res.matrix())
```

And I get this error:

```
 File "/home/dan/anaconda3/envs/q_env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/autoray/autoray.py", line 80, in do
    return get_lib_fn(backend, fn)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 6 is different from 9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bug in Pennylane for qutrits, here is a link to the [issue](https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane/issues/4367). If you would like a short-term solution you could do.

```
import pennylane as qml
import numpy as np

TSub = qml.adjoint(qml.TAdd)
TRZ_01 = lambda phi: qml.QutritUnitary(np.kron(np.eye(3),qml.TRZ.compute_matrix(phi)), wires=(0,1))
TRZ_02 = lambda phi: qml.QutritUnitary(np.kron(np.eye(3),qml.TRZ.compute_matrix(phi, subspace=(0,2))), wires=(0,1))

res = qml.TAdd(wires=[0, 1]) @ TRZ_01(0.5) @ \
    TRZ_02(0.5) @ TSub(wires=[0, 1])

print(res.matrix())
```

I recommend checking `np.diag(res.matrix())` as it will be diagonal.

Also, for an intuitive understanding of this circuit, it is implementing a rotation of phase by phi for states where qutrits are the same and -phi/2 otherwise.
More information on the algorithm can be found in my [paper](https://%20https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2308.08050), and the source code is [here](https://github.com/QSAR-UBC/QT-CorGI).

I hope this is helpful!

Please feel free to reach out if you have any more questions.

Comment: It works. I was indeed reading your paper. In the code you are not specifying subspace=(0,1) for TRZ_01 but I guess it's the default behavior.